# Kendo Grid UI with custom function

Tags: function, button, kendo-ui, delete-row

I would like to have a delete button that uses kendo default design [button design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6YCF.png) that uses my own function, may I know how could I do this?

This is the code for the button:

```
   columns.Command(command => { command.Destroy(); }).Width(30);
```

Comment: Hey New2Programming . Your question is not clear if you are looking for that specific design or you are having difficulty in attaching function to it . any way i have given answer below . if you are looking for something else let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is simple all you have to do is run a java script method when user click on delete button. Here is one way you can accomplish it.

```
    columns.Command(c => c.Custom("Delete").Click("deleteRecord"));
```

**Javascript**

```
   function deleteRecord(e) {
     var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
     if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete : ' + dataItem.name)) {
         var grid = $("#gridNAME").data("kendoGrid");
         grid.dataSource.remove(dataItem);
         grid.dataSource.sync();
         grid.refresh();
     }
 }
```